# Is there any simpler way to find a remainder in multiple divisions?

Tags: polynomials

I got a question as follows.

> $3x-5$ is the remainder when unknown $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2-x+1$
>   that has relatively complicated  roots. Find the remainder when $f(x)$
>   is divided by $(x^2-x+1)(x-1)$. Express your answer in terms of
>   unknown $f(1)$, $x^2-x+1$, and $3x-5$.

### Attempt

As the divisor is a cubic, then the remainder is at most a quadratic $a x^2 + bx +c$. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the complicated root of $x^2-x+1$.

Now I have

\begin{align}
3x_1-5 &= a x_1^2 + bx_1 + c\\
3x_2-5 &= a x_2^2 + b x_2 +c \\
f(1) &= a + b +c
\end{align}

Finding $a$, $b$ and $c$ seems to be extremely tedious for me.

### Question

Is there any simpler method to find the remainder in question?

### Edit:

I have edited the quoted problem. The answer can be in terms of the divisor $x^2-x+1$ as well as the remainder $3x-5$.

Comment: I was born without mathematics in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is as follows:

- $f(x) = (x^2-x+1)q(x) + 3x-5$
- $q(x) = (x-1)r(x) + c$

Hence,

$$f(x) = (x^2-x+1)((x-1)r(x) + c) + 3x -5$$ $$= (x^2-x+1)(x-1)r(x) + c(x^2-x+1) + 3x-5$$

Now you can find $c$:

$$f(1) =c -2 \Leftrightarrow c=2+f(1)$$

So, you get

$$f(x) = (x^2-x+1)(x-1)r(x) + \color{blue}{(2+f(1))(x^2-x+1) + 3x-5}$$

I leave it up to you to collect like terms of the remainder as it suits you.